# how get max value from a count on JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

im working with JPA JPQL querys im not an expert,just started studing it some days ago. 
I have this query

```
SELECT u.nombres, COUNT(p) AS count FROM Usuario u,PostPaso pp
JOIN pp.post p
WHERE u.idUsuario = pp.idUsuario
GROUP BY u.idUsuario
ORDER BY count desc
```

it returns the  number of post of each user, i want it to show the user with the higher number of post, i have tried with max but i've had syntax errors,i want to do it in the query not in the java layer as i have found as an answer in some other pages

Comment: You could use `setMaxResults` which would be the analogy of `LIMIT` or `TOP` in SQL.

Comment: is there any other way to make it in the query or just with that method?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the query?"  Do you want a pure SQL answer?  If so, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Which _database_ are you using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server), and are you really looking for a raw SQL query?

Comment: postgresSQL, yep the raw JPQL to get the higher value

Comment: Do you need to worry about ties?

Comment: sorry i didnt get it, what do you mean?